# selecting a value from multiple tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have added search option to a project. There I used jquery auto complete feature to display related result for the keyword when some particular user is entering in search text box.

this is my php script..

```
<?php

require_once('database.php');

if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {

    $queryString = $dbc->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

    if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
        //$query = $dbc->query("SELECT subjects FROM subject WHERE subjects LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
        $q = "SELECT tutor_name FROM tutors WHERE tutor_name LIKE '%$queryString%' LIMIT 10";

        $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q);

        if($q) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$row['tutor_name'].'\');">'.$row['tutor_name'].'</li>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
        }
    } else {

    }
} else {
    echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
}

?>
```

This is working properly for me.. but my problem is I need to check multiple tables with typing keyword. Here I use only one table.. anyone can tell me how can I attach my other tables to this query?

Comment: does all you previous questions were all unanswered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `UNION`

```
SELECT keyword 
FROM
(
    SELECT tutor_Name AS keyword FROM tutors
    UNION
    SELECT subject_name AS keyword FROM subjects
    UNION
    SELECT institute_name AS keyword FROM institutes
) s
WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
LIMIT 10
```

you query is also vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: no... there are different field names and tables.. Example: tutor_name from tutor table, subject_name from subjects table, institute_name from institutes table etc...

Comment: what does mean in this line's s ') s'

Comment: it's called the `Alias` of the subquery.,

Comment: I have anther problem.. now my autocomplete box display all result in subjects,tutor names, institutes etc to related keyword. Now I want to categorize them in autocomplete box.. ex: subjects under subject category, tutor name under tutor category etc..

Comment: the best way to do now is to create a separate question regarding the new problem. this has been solved and the new problem does not have any relation on this one.

Comment: ok.. I created new question.. this is its link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560808/categorize-auto-complete-data

Answer (score 0):

The below `Query merge three tables` that `returns` you only those `selective records present in tables` on the `basis of common column in the tables`.

```
SELECT tutor_name FROM yourDB
LEFT JOIN tableA ON tutor_name = '%$queryString%'
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tutor_name = '%$queryString%';
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: if there are different field names and tables.. Example: tutor_name from tutor table, subject_name from subjects table, institute_name from institutes table etc... then how can I use this query?

Comment: LEFT JOIN subjectTbl ON subject_name = '%$queryString%', it should be this way.