# Categorize auto complete data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I used auto complete box to my searching text box. Its working properly for me... this is my script..

```
<?php

require_once('database.php');

if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {

    $queryString = $dbc->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

    if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
        $q = "SELECT keyword 
                FROM (
                    SELECT tname AS keyword FROM t
                    UNION
                    SELECT sname AS keyword FROM sub
                    UNION
                    SELECT cname AS keyword FROM c
                    UNION
                    SELECT iname AS keyword FROM i
                ) s
              WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
              LIMIT 10";

        $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q);

        if($q) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$row['keyword'].'\');">'.$row['keyword'].'</li>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
        }
    } else {

    }
} else {
    echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
}

?>
```

problem is my autocomplete box display all result in subjects,tutor names, institutes etc to related keyword. Now I want to categorize them in autocomplete box.. ex: subjects under subject category, tutor name under tutor category etc... what i am trying to do is something similar to facebook search option..

This is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function lookup(inputString) {

        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }

</script>
```

can anybody help me to this?
Thank you.

Comment: if you are using jQueryUI autocomplete there is a demo for categories .Look at the  source code, and make your data match example  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a drop down near the search text input to select category or multiple checkbox to see what union you would have to make? I would recommend you Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/

Try

```
SELECT 1 as type,tname AS keyword FROM t
                    UNION
                    SELECT 2 as type,sname AS keyword FROM sub
                    UNION
                    SELECT 3 as type,cname AS keyword FROM c
                    UNION
                    SELECT 4 as type,iname AS keyword FROM i

foreach($results as $result)
{
    switch($result['type'])
    {
        case 1:
        $cat_1[]=$result;
        break;

        case 2:
        $cat_2[]=$result;
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: my queryString varible check 4 tables and display autocomplete box with those values related to the keyword entering by a user. Its working perfectly. so now I need to categorize display results in autocompele box. clear?

Comment: You can add a type column do a sort and output however you want

Comment: thanks for responce... can you tell me how can I create categorize auto complete box using this query?

Comment: you could make a switch and put each result in a specific array and iterate afterwards

Comment: can you give me example with this logic?

Comment: I have 3 categories 'Subjects, Tutors, Institutes, city' and auto complete results should display under these categories. Is it possible with your logic?